# Does the tensor product give another tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Suppose you have have a set of tensors (A) where the set elements are $${T^{ij},T^i_j,T_{ij},G_{nm},G^n_m},G^{nm}$$would $$T^{ij}
⊗G_{nm}$$ be a some new arbitrary tensor $$X^{ij}_{nm}$$ or $$T^i_j
⊗G^{nm}=X^{inm}_j$$ and likewise for all other combinations of tensors that belong to the set A? Or is this completely wrong?

Comment: the tensor products of rank two tensors are tensors of rank four

Comment: ok thanks, so i assume that the tensor product of two tenors of rank 1 you get a new tensor of rank 2? And likewise for 2,3,...n indices?

Comment: a f f i r m a t i v e

Comment: Notation: When tensors are written with indices, they normally refer to the real- or complex-valued components of a tensor relative a basis induced by a choice of coordinate system. Then the tensor product sign $\otimes$ is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

The tensor product
$$
\otimes: (V^{\otimes r}\otimes V^{*\otimes s}) \times (V^{\otimes r'}\otimes V^{*\otimes s'}) \to V^{\otimes( r + r')}\otimes V^{*\otimes( s + s' )}
$$
is a bilinear map the acts as follows on simple tensors
$$
((\bigotimes_i u_i) \otimes (\bigotimes_j f_j),(\bigotimes_k v_k) \otimes (\bigotimes_l g_l)) \mapsto (\bigotimes_i u_i) \otimes (\bigotimes_k v_k) \otimes (\bigotimes_j f_j) \otimes(\bigotimes_l g_l)
$$
where $u_i,v_j \in V$ and $f_j,g_l \in V^*$. (I,m not sure about the reordering whether it is a convention or it should be held as it is.)

Sorry for the notation that is the shortest for the general case.

Comment: ok thanks, so does the product of two tensors give another tensor? For example, $$T^iG_j=B^i_j$$

Comment: That's the idea of the answer